# How to find out if request is HTTPS or HTTP in express.js with apache reversed proxy?

Tags: node.js, apache, http, express, https

I am trying to validate a request to see if it is HTTPS or HTTP. My express application is running on port 1337. Apache functions as a reverse proxy, on port 80 without ssl certificates and on port 443 for https request.

I've tried the following:

```
console.log("Is secure HTTPS: "+req.secure);
console.log("Is encrypted: "+req.connection.encrypted);
console.log("Proxy "+req.header('x-forwarded-proto'));
console.log(req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'])
```

When requesting from chrome with https it prints:

```
Is secure HTTPS: false
Is encrypted: undefined
Proxy undefined
undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to explicitly tell Apache to set `x-forwarded-proto`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you can use `req.headers['x-forwarded'proto']`. Express sets the `req.secure` field only if you've set "trust proxy", e.g.

```
app.set('trust proxy', 'loopback')
```

Comment: I tried your approach. However I get this error from apache2: Invalid command 'RequestHeader', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the serve

Comment: I had to enable the headers in apache with the command `a2enmod headers` and now req.secure returns true on https calls. Thanks for your help!